# Search workbook for cell value and copy entire row and headers

Tags: excel, vba

I have tried every possible method to search and find the solution to this problem but to no avail, My problem is to search a particular cell value in different sheets in a workbook and copy the entire row along with their headers (Every sheet has different header example, Lab1,Name, Date, Lab Test Type, LabType N, Name, Date, Test Type and so on) and loop through until last value is find with their respective headers. Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated and please forgive me for not knowing the right way to ask the question because i am totally a newbie to this forum.
This code below is giving me the results of the search cell, but because every search result has its own header which i am not getting at the result, as it only pasting the entire row of cell only through loop but not their headers.
Here are the example.
Sheet2 has Name Date    Age Sex Cell No Test Type in Range A1:F1
Sheet3 has Name Date    Age Sex Cell No Test Type2 Xray Range A1:G1
Sheet4 has Name Date    Age Sex Cell No Test Type3 XRay ECG A1:H1

```
Option Explicit
Option Compare Text '< ignore case
Sub AllRecordSearchMacroForPhone()
    Dim FirstAddress As String
    Dim c As Range, Sheet As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Range("D1")
    If rng = Empty Then Exit Sub
    For Each Sheet In Sheets
        If Sheet.Name <> "Sheet1" Then
            With Sheet.Columns(5)
                Set c = .find(rng, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
                If Not c Is Nothing Then
                    FirstAddress = c.Address
                    Do
                        c.EntireRow.Copy _
                              Destination:=Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
                        Set c = .FindNext(c)
                    Loop Until c.Address = FirstAddress
                End If
            End With
        End If
    Next Sheet
    Set c = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add marked line to your code:

```
If Not c Is Nothing Then
  >>Sheet.Rows(1).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Sheets("Sheet1").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    FirstAddress = c.Address
```

Comment: Egan Wolf, You are a champ, your suggested line did the trick and solved my problem, Thank you very much, you have just saved my life.

Comment: Ok, so it's working fine? Was wondering what your previous comment was about ;)

Comment: LOL i had to crossed checked again and found that macro proved me wrong and it was working perfectly.